# Building a call API project with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes

I would like to build a call `API` laravel project, separate the front-end and back-end, but how? 
All the `API` are writing in the `routes/api.php`, but the job that return a view still live in `routes/web.php` ,
is that normal ? if not, what should I do ?
The code like ...

**routes/web.php:**

```
Route::get('/book/{id}',function(){ return view('book.show')->with('id',$id) ;});
```

**show.blade.php:**

```
...
$(function(){
    $.ajax{
        url: 'api/book/{{ $id }}',
        ....
    }
});
...
```

**routes/api.php:**

```
//return the book data that id = {id}    
Route::get('/book/{id}','BookController@show');
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest that use **Lumen** since you are building **API**. Take a look at [this](https://lumen.laravel.com/)

Comment: They're wanting a front end as well as a back end. Lumen is a bad solution for this situation.

Comment: If you're building an API it's assumed you will use a frontend framework for fronted. Thus not requiring the whole Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it correctly.

One of the benefits of separating web and api routes is you have more granular control over applying middlewares.

Take a look at app/Kernel.php file:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

As @angad-dubey mentioned its good practise to separate them out so that the web deals with the front end and the api routes for ... Api calls.

I tend to separate mine further by adding an admin.php within the routes folder, so that my backend routes are also separated, Thus you don't have one file with a long list of routes to search through, and this way as shown above you can append different middleware to them and not to the others, which could cause issues in the long term